# Identityserver4 not sending access_token

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, identityserver4

I'm trying to create react spa with authentication. I'm using identityserver4 for OIDC provider. Whenever I login, I am redirected to login page and after providing credentials, I'm redirected to SPA, but UserManger does not have access_token.

I've tried to play with Client on server side, but none of that worked.

For Frontend I'm using this example https://github.com/Franpastoragusti/oidc-react-app , but converted to typescript
And backend is slightly modified Identityserver quickstart.

This is my Client in Config.cs

```cs
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "primrose.web",
                    ClientName = "Primrose Web Application",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = 120,
                  AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,

                    RedirectUris = { 
                        "http://localhost:3000/callback",
                        "http://localhost:3000/silentRenew",
                    },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = 
                    { 
                        "http://localhost:5000/account/login"
                    },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:3000" },

                    AllowedScopes =
                    { 
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "primrose.web"
                    },
                }
            };
        }
```

This is my oidc configuration in client app:

```js
export const IDENTITY_CONFIG: any = {
  authority: "http://localhost:5000", //(string): The URL of the OIDC provider.
  client_id: "primrose.web", //(string): Your client application's identifier as registered with the OIDC provider.
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/callback", //The URI of your client application to receive a response from the OIDC provider.
  login: "http://localhost:5000/account/login",
  automaticSilentRenew: false, //(boolean, default: false): Flag to indicate if there should be an automatic attempt to renew the access token prior to its expiration.
  loadUserInfo: true, //(boolean, default: true): Flag to control if additional identity data is loaded from the user info endpoint in order to populate the user's profile.
  silent_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/silentRenew", //(string): The URL for the page containing the code handling the silent renew.
  post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5000/account/login", // (string): The OIDC post-logout redirect URI.
  audience: "primrose.web", //is there a way to specific the audience when making the jwt
  responseType: "id_token token", //(string, default: 'id_token'): The type of response desired from the OIDC provider.
  grantType: "password",
  scope: "openid profile primrose.web", //(string, default: 'openid'): The scope being requested from the OIDC provider.
  webAuthResponseType: "id_token token"
};

export const METADATA_OIDC: any = {
  issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
  jwks_uri: "http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  authorization_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize",
  token_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
  userinfo_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/userinfo",
  end_session_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/endsession",
  check_session_iframe: "http://localhost:5000/connect/checksession",
  revocation_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/revocation",
  introspection_endpoint: "http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect"
};
```

this is what usermanager returns when addUserLoaded event is fired

```
access_token: undefined
expires_at: undefined
id_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSU...(I deleted rest of the token)"
profile:
amr: ["pwd"]
auth_time: 1564597858
email: "pipa@papa.pl"
idp: "local"
name: "pipa@papa.pl"
preferred_username: "pipa@papa.pl"
sid: "2044d39c30e316722516f6d376e24838"
sub: "c0ca848c-8d2d-48e6-829f-e1d29838ecef"
__proto__: Object
refresh_token: undefined
scope: "openid profile primrose.web"
session_state: "kmFYyCDxsql8D4-WD7J07OwW4zhMDdqLjDkHriNuwqg.852977a2a19ba24a7bb5a12d389bebfd"
state: undefined
token_type: undefined
expired: (...)
expires_in: (...)
scopes: (...)
__proto__: Object
```

I want to retrieve this access token from OIDC provider in my client app, but it comes undefined

Comment: Does your client have the AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser option set?

Comment: As you can see, it has. But this case is closed, as I managed to get it working by following IdentityServer4 documentation. I've limited IDENTITY_CONFIG properties